# How can I get the latest item price and new price in mysql query

Tags: mysql, sql

i have data in table database :

| name | price | dateupdate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 300 | 2021-06-12 |
| A | 500 | 2021-12-01 |
| B | 700 | 2022-01-01 |
| A | 800 | 2022-01-25 |
| B | 1000 | 2022-02-12 |

how to display data in mysql query to be like this:

| name | price | dateupdate | price | dateupdate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 500 | 2021-12-01 | 800 | 2022-01-25 |
| B | 700 | 2022-01-01 | 1000 | 2022-02-12 |

Comment: What is your MySQL version?

Comment: I have reverted your question to what you originally asked.  Please don't change your question after others have already answered it.

Answer (score 0):

We can use pivoting logic with `ROW_NUMBER` here:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY name ORDER BY dateupdate) rn
    FROM yourTable
)

SELECT name,
       MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 1 THEN price END) AS price1,
       MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 1 THEN dateupdate END) AS dateupdate1,
       MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 2 THEN price END) AS price2,
       MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 2 THEN dateupdate END) AS dateupdate2
FROM cte
GROUP BY name
ORDER BY name;
```

The above assumes your are using MySQL 8+.  If you're *not* using the latest version of MySQL, you may try the following version:

```sql
SELECT
    t1.name,
    MAX(CASE WHEN t1.dateupdate = t2.mindateupdate THEN t1.price END) AS price1,
    MAX(CASE WHEN t1.dateupdate = t2.mindateupdate THEN t1.dateupdate END) AS dateupdate1,
    MAX(CASE WHEN t1.dateupdate = t2.maxdateupdate THEN t1.price END) AS price2,
    MAX(CASE WHEN t1.dateupdate = t2.maxdateupdate THEN t1.dateupdate END) AS dateupdate2
FROM yourTable t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT name, MIN(dateupdate) AS mindateupdate, MAX(dateupdate) AS maxdateupdate
    FROM yourTable
    GROUP BY name
) t2
    ON t2.name = t1.name
GROUP BY
    t1.name;
```

Comment: I try you query "Unreqognize statment type . ( near WITH )

Comment: sorry I don't understand how to apply it

Comment: @FeriDerPanzer I suspect that you may be using an early version of MySQL.  I have given you an option which should run even there.

Comment: what if the name A has 3 rows of data, how do you display only the last data?